# Beautifulsoup get data-value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to catch the `data-value=2538` with BeautifulSoup. The result should be 2538.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u = '<span class="mainValueAmount" data-peak="19980" data-timestamp="2018-09-27T10:00:00" data-value="2538">-</span>, <span class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_energyYieldWidget_energyYieldValue">2739</span>, <span class="mainValueAmount simpleTextFit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PublicPagePlaceholder1_PageUserControl_ctl00_PublicPageLoadFixPage_carbonWidget_carbonReductionValue">1.9</span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(u, "html.parser")

s = soup.select_one('.mainValueAmount')

print(s)
```

So, how do I catch the 2538 value?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use attrs:

```
soup.select_one("span").attrs.get("data-value", None)
```